# Splunk: search with starttime and endtime with format "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"

Tags: splunk

I'm new to Splunk and I want to do a search that specifies the start and end time.

I am using curl to automate the process and calling it from a bash script.

I have the `starttime` and `endtime` values I want but they do not have the %d/%m/%Y:%H%M%S" format and converting my "%Y%m%d H:%M%S" in bash will be ugly.

Is there a way to use `timeformat` to make my life easier?

My curl command is made up like this:

```
curl -u "$user:$pass" -k https://$splunkserver/services/search/jobs/export      \
                -d search='search "'"$search"'" | search starttime="'"$STARTTIME"'" | search endtime="'$ENDTIME"'" | search index=$index sourcetype=$sourcetype'
```

If I use these values, it works:

```
STARTTIME=01/20/2022:23:59:00
ENDTIME=01/21/2022:01:00:00
```

But fails when use the values I have:

```
STARTTIME="20220120 23:59:00"
ENDTIME="20220121 01:00:00"
```

Feel free to suggest other improvements to my Splunk code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your human-readable timestamp to Unix epoch time - since `_time` is *always* [in Unix epoch time](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/DateandTimeFunctions)

Check out strftime.org for the exact calls

Then you can send this in your `curl` call:

```
curl -u "$user:$pass" -k https://$splunkserver/services/search/jobs/export -d search='search "'"$search"'" | search index=$index sourcetype=$sourcetype' earliest=$STARTTIME latest=$ENDTIME'
```

Comment: I see you have changed starttime to earliest and endtime to latest - is that an improvement in speed etc?

Sadly I still have to convert my "YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS" dates - albeit now to unix epoch seconds

I was hoping to (ab)use Splunk's date commands - I will give it a try though

Comment: @TinkerPhil - events are all cataloged by Unix epoch time (see this comment on [r/splunk](https://www.reddit.com/r/Splunk/comments/osrcr6/comment/h6r8vw7 & this [docs.splunk](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Indexer/HowSplunkstoresindexes#Bucket_naming_conventions) page)). Use Unix epoch time. It's *much* easier :)

Comment: Turns out that linux's date command is happier working with unix epoch time than the Solaris/Oracle date command - and it could also do the data manipulations I wanted - so it all works ok - Thanks!